# make a view scroll horizontally rather than vertically

Tags: javascript, android, ios, scroll, titanium

I'm struggling to make a scroll view scroll sidewards rather than up and down in titanium. I'll need the solution for both iOS and Android.

```
var challengesScrollView= Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top: '60%',
    height: c1Container.height,
    width: '60%',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    zIndex: 9000,
    /* left & right work too */
    contentHeight:'auto',
});

challengesScrollView.add(c1Container);
challengesScrollView.add(c2Container);
challengesScrollView.add(c3Container);
mainContainer.add(challengesScrollView);
```

UPDATE:

my mainContainer is the following:

```
var mainContainer= Ti.UI.createView({
    left: '5%',
    right:'5%',
    top: '9%',
    bottom:'15%',
});
```

and c1Container is:

```
var c1Container= Ti.UI.createView({
    top:'1%',
    width:'70dp',
    height: '90dp',
    zIndex:20, 
    left:'10dp',
    backgroundColor:'#3b214a',
    borderRadius: 5
});
```

and it contains the following:

```
var c1PicView= Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '55dp',
    height: '55dp',
    top: '5%',
    borderRadius: 5,
    //backgroundColor:'pink',
    zIndex:5
});

var c1Pic= Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:'girl.jpg',
    width: c1PicView.width,
    height: c1PicView.height,
    zIndex:5
});

var cName= 'Mary';
var c1Name=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color: 'white',
    text: cName,
    font:{fontSize: '14sp'},
    top: '60dp' 
});

c1Container.add(c1PicView);
c1PicView.add(c1Pic);
c1Container.add(c1Name);
```

c2 is the same as c1 apart from the name

I'm not sure how to position c1Container, c2Container and c3Container etc. so that they will just add on the view sidewards. I can't give actual pixel, left or right positions because the scroll view could have up to 20 mini containers. All help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple thing is that you just need to set **layout** property to **horizontal**.

Comment: Hi I used the layout property as per romainsalles suggestion. However if you reaad my comment on his answer, I still have an issue

Comment: ok then also you need to set **contentWidth to 'auto'** as well.
try it.

Comment: can you tell me what is **mainContainer and c1Container,c2Container**?

Comment: ok,try to set mainContainer's height and width to 'auto' and remove right and bottom property of mainContainer.

Comment: I have changed my mainContainers properties as suggested just to test but it didn't change my scrollview layout

Comment: @mitual Bhalia OK i changed the scrollview's width and height to auto and it worked :) Thanks

Comment: Spoke too soon. It moved my 3rd container to the right place but when I added a 4th it was placed underneath

Comment: I needed to change the width, height, contentwidth and contentheight to numbers. When they were auto, it didn't work

Comment: ok try to set Ti.UI.SIZE instead of 'auto' because 'auto' is deprecated from 3.0.x releases.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can use a **ScrollView** (and it should work both on iOS and android).

I've just tried this code which works just fine :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var challengesScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    top:             '60%',
    height:          '30%',
    width:           '60%',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    layout:          'horizontal'
});
win.add(challengesScrollView);

function addView() {
    challengesScrollView.add(Ti.UI.createView({
        left: '10dp',
        width: '100dp',
        height: '100dp',
        backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
    }));

    setTimeout(addView, 2000);
}

win.addEventListener('open', addView);

win.open();
```

This code add a **new View** to the **ScrollView** every 2 seconds and, as you wish, the **ScrollView**'s width change every time.

The property **layout: 'horizontal'** is used to place each view horizontally in the **ScrollView**. Thus, you don't have to calculate the absolute position of each view.

If this property doesn't solve your issue, maybe you should share more code (for example the construction of your containers). Otherwise, it will be difficult to help you ;)

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your response. I am really close to the solution now. The only thing now, is that once I add a container to the scroll view that doesn't fit within the scroll view, it is added underneath rather than to the side. Do you understand what I am trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

use Horizontal scroll widget in android

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I'm using titanium. I only included it in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

`UIScrollView` scrolls in different directions depending on its `contentSize` property. If you make the `contentSize`'s `width` larger then the actual width of the scroll view, it should scroll horizontally.

Comment: thanks. But is there a way how I can deal with adding my container views side by side each other within the scroll view, dynamically?

Comment: I guessing you should use some sort of a loop and just set their frames accordingly. Or I'd just use a UICollectionView, which does that for you - and more. :-)